# With Google DFP (Small Business) is it possible to disable AdSense in an Ad Slot on a per-request basis?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

**Setup**: I run a network of websites that target different hobby niches and have a section dedicated to community classifieds. I serve advertising on these sites through Google DFP for Small Business with AdSense enabled on the slots.

**Problem**: One of the next sites in my network will be targeting the firearms/shooting industry and as such the classifieds section will not comply with the prohibited content guidelines of AdSense regarding the sale (or coordination of sale) of weapons. I work very hard to comply with the guidelines of my partners even if I don't understand/agree with them and after talking with many people have decided that the best option is to disable AdSense serving on that section of that website, while leaving it on for the rest of the network.

**Solution**: Right now my only idea for this is to duplicate all my site's ad slots and tack a "_sensitive" onto the end of each one (eg. header and header_sensitive) conditionally registering ad slots based on whether or not I am in the sensitive section of the sensitive site. My hope however is that there may be a way to accomplish this without duplicating all my ad slots possibly with some sort of options to the GA_googleFillSlot() call that allows me to say "load ads from this slot but do not serve AdSense no matter what."

Comment: I can't seem to find an answer, so although you solution does sound good, I'd experiment with disabling the adense within the google.com/dfp ui and then seeing if updating adsense settings via the following urls enable it :) http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90779 or if your using Google Publisher Tag http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650154&expand=pubservice_details#set

Answer (score 1):

[This question has been asked in the Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/dfp/Rii_C70oqX4/FcA6qURjBi4J).

There does not appear to be a good way of doing this.  The only answer there suggests that you use custom criteria and run your AdSense through an order rather than configuring AdSense as the fallback.